# pd.info() in AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'info'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just use pandas to write a load_data function, then I have bug in my code, I don't know how to deal with that? and my code `df.info()` alway has errors `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'info', or the output is` 0`or` none`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
from io import StringIO

def load_data():
    buffer = StringIO()
    #df.info(buf = buffer)
    #buffer.getvalue()
    #with open('work.csv', ';') as f:
    pd.read_csv('work.csv',';', encoding="utf-8")
    return 0

df = load_data()
print(df.info())
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 740 entries, 0 to 739
Data columns (total 21 columns):
 #   Column                           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                           --------------  -----  
 0   ID                               740 non-null    int64  
 1   Reason for absence               740 non-null    int64  
 2   Month of absence                 740 non-null    int64  
 3   Day of the week                  740 non-null    int64  
 4   Seasons                          740 non-null    int64  
 5   Transportation expense           740 non-null    int64  
 6   Distance from Residence to Work  740 non-null    int64  
 7   Service time                     740 non-null    int64  
 8   Age                              740 non-null    int64  
 9   Work load Average/day            740 non-null    float64
 10  Hit target                       740 non-null    int64
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `load_data` function is *returning 0* and not the dataframe that has been loaded. You need to modify your return statement in order for this to work as expected:

```
def load_data():
    buffer = StringIO()
    #df.info(buf = buffer)
    #buffer.getvalue()
    #with open('work.csv', ';') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv('work.csv',';', encoding="utf-8")
    return df
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah, I need to study how to return the value.  I'm fresher of the python...And I find another way is just `return pd.read_csv('work.csv',';')` also can run.